# ASP.NET MVC Using Multiple user controls on a single .aspx(view)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
   I am getting this following error , when i am tring to having two user controls in one page.
```

**The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[Data.EventLog]' but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Data.Notes]'.**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Test
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Test</h2>

    <% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/UserControl/Tracking.ascx"); %>
     <% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/UserControl/Notes.ascx"); %>
 </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Notes.ascx` control is strongly-typed, but you are not passing a model in your call to `RenderPartial`. Hence, the model for the page is passed instead, which is the wrong type for the user control. You need to pass a model in your call to `RenderPartial`.

For example, if the event log page model has a property called `NotesModel`:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyNamespace.EventLogModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Test
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Test</h2>

    <% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/UserControl/Tracking.ascx"); %>
     <% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/UserControl/Notes.ascx", Model.NotesModel); %>
 </asp:Content>
```

Note that I've:

1. Changed the `Inherits` bit of the `@Page` directive to specify the model type and,
2. Added the `model` argument to `RenderPartial`.

You would of course need to populate `Model.NotesModel` in your controller. If it's `null` you'll see the same bug you presently see.

Comment: I am actually new to this , could you please give me an example of this?Thanks